# Forward the same argument to variadic tuple constructor in C++

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, variadic-templates, stdtuple

TL;DR below

I am trying to write some C++ code using a package for multicore processing. The package has a nice sender class that I use to send messages between the threads. It looks something like this:

```cpp
// structs provided by the package
struct GlobalVarsContainer {
    // some global vars
};

template<typename ...Ts>
struct sender {
    GlobalVarsContainer* my_container;
    sender (GlobalVarsContainer& c) : my_container(&c);
    void send(Ts... args) {
        // send the messages of types Ts
    };
};
```

The constructor of this class is actually a bit more involved, so I would like to have the constructor called only once.
I tought of using a container-type for all the senders I need, so something like this:

```cpp
typedef std::tuple<
    sender<uint32_t,uint32_t>,
    sender<uint32_t,double>,
    sender<uint32_t,double>
> sender_container_1_t;
typedef std::tuple<
    sender<uint32_t,double>,
    sender<uint32_t,double>,
    sender<uint32_t,double>
> sender_container_2_t;
```

Now I can construct a `sender_container_1_t` and pass it by reference to all my functions, hurray!
But this is ugly, and you have to instantiate the container like so:

```
GlobalVarsContainer gvc1, gvc2;
sender_container_1_t c1(gvc1, gvc1, gvc1);
sender_container_2_t c2(gvc2, gvc2, gvc2);
```

And I would like to have something of the form

```
GlobalVarsContainer gvc1, gvc2;
// Should have a tuple of senders of type sender<uint32_t,uint32_t>, sender<uint32_t,double> and sender<uint32_t,double>, all constructed with a reference to gvc as an argument.
sender_container<uint32_t,double,double> c1(gvc1);
// Should have a tuple of senders of type sender<uint32_t,double>, sender<uint32_t, double> and sender<uint32_t, double>, all constructed with a reference to gvc as an argument.
sender_container<double,double,double> c2(gvc2);
```

So I thought of using a variadic container struct, like so:

```
// My sender container
template<typename... Ts>
struct SenderContainer {
    std::tuple<sender<uint32_t, Ts>...> my_senders;
    // What to do for the constructor ?
};
```

But I do not know what to do such that I can do `SenderContainer<uint32_t,double,double> my_container(gvc1)` such that the `gvc1` is forwarded to the constructor of all the senders. Does anyone have a tip?

TL;DR:
If I have a variadic struct template

```cpp
template<typename ...Ts>
struct Bar {
    Bar(Foo f){};
}
```

Can I make a container of the form

```cpp
template<typename ...Ts>
struct BarContainer{
    std::tuple<Bar<int,Ts>...> bars
}
```

such that I can call `BarContainer<int, double, long> newBarContainer(f)` and the `Foo f` is forwarded to all constructors of the `BarContainer::bars`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create dummy structure to allow your [pack expansion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack):

```
template <typename> struct tag{};

template<typename ...Ts>
struct Bar {
    Bar(Foo f){};
};

template<typename ...Ts>
struct BarContainer{
    BarContainer(Foo f) : bars{(tag<Ts>{}, f)...} {}

    std::tuple<Bar<int,Ts>...> bars;
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/35331fc010d06a98)

Comment: I guess it works. Do you have a link to a cppref page that explains this magic?

Comment: Pack expansion is possible is several contexts, you just have to create one which match your need.